# I want the logo to appear animatedly when the navbar becomes sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://weartuality.com/

You see the black navbar on that site. There is no logo on that black navbar, but when it becomes sticky, the logo appears. How can I do this using html css javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for the scroll event and show/hide the logo if a certain Y scroll position is reached.

```js
const logoElement = document.querySelector(".logo"); // <--- update this selector
const checkLogo = () => {
   if (window.scrollY > 100) {// <-- your non-sticky nav's height here
       logoElement.style.setProperty("transform", "scale(1)");
   } else {
       logoElement.style.setProperty("transform", "scale(0)");
   }
}
checkLogo();
window.addEventListener("scroll", checkLogo);
```

CSS:

```css
.my-logo {
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: transform .3s;
}
```

Comment: I will try now in visual studio code thanks for now:)

Comment: I couldn't, it didn't work.

Comment: I'm probably still missing something, your code is not wrong. But i am new to javascript what should i do this please help more.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is `logoElement` defined correctly? Also make sure the js is below your HTML or in a DOMContentLoaded event

Comment: Actually I copied and pasted your code. And yes my script codes are below. I'm probably not specifying something inside the functions or I'm making a mistake on the css side.

Comment: OK, is it showing any errors? For example, unless you defined `logoElement` as the element of the logo the code will crash.

Comment: I am getting the following error in DevTools: Uncaught ReferenceError: logoElement is not defined at checkLogo

Comment: It probably doesn't work because I didn't select elements with id and class in the script codes.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to define the variable correctly. You just have to edit the selector

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I can't get it to work again can I message you?

Comment: I'm doing it right now.